# divs are not sorted properly when searching with html css js

Tags: javascript, css

As can be seen here, there is probably a problem in my css and js code and I cannot find this problem. When I make a call, there is a problem as you can see in the photo below. Results not sorted properly within divs

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var count = 0;
  var table=document.createElement("table");
  for(var i=0;i<(10);i++){ //SATIR
var tr=document.createElement("tr");
table.appendChild(tr);
 for(var j=0;j<3;j++){ // SÜTUN
     var td=document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML=
        '<div id="'+count+'" class="emote_container">'+

            '<span id="'+count+'"  class="emote_name_lbl"> '+count+' </span>'+
        '</div>';

     tr.appendChild(td);
     count++;
    }
}
    document.getElementById("emotes_area").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("emotes_area").appendChild(table);
});


document.getElementById("input_search").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var searchValue = this.value.toLowerCase(); // Get the lowercase value of the input
  var emoteContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("emote_container");

  for (var i = 0; i < emoteContainers.length; i++) {
  var emoteName = emoteContainers[i].getElementsByClassName("emote_name_lbl")[0].innerText.toLowerCase();

  if (emoteName.includes(searchValue)) {
      emoteContainers[i].style.display = "flex"; // Show the emote container
  } else {
      emoteContainers[i].style.display = "none"; // Hide the emote container
  }
  }
});
```

```css
.emotes_area{
  position: absolute;
  width: 404px;
  height: 703px;
  top: 165px;
  left: 62px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 1px;
background-color: #00000000;
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.emote_container{
  position: relative;
  width: 123px;
  height: 131px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(82.29% 82.29% at 50% 50%, rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.5) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 90%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px  #81818173;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2.7px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Emotes Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="emotes_area"  id="emotes_area">
<!-- <div class=""></div> -->
</div>

<input class="search_input" id="input_search" type="text" placeholder="Search Something...">

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not properly sorted"? Are the "blank" blocks in the grid the problem?

Comment: Hello, yes, I do not want the gaps in between as seen in the picture. I want the results found to be lined up neatly side by side from the beginning.
I hope I could explain. @StephanPieterse

Comment: Please include an example of the desired output

Comment: The main problem is that you are using a table to structure this. You are only setting div elements inside the table cells to `display: none` - of course that doesn't change the structure of the table itself. If you want those elements to "flow" to close any gaps that filtering might leave - then a table is about the last thing you should be using for this. Go flexbox or grid.

Comment: I want it to be ;

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1030511778213417023/1176420421562798130/d.png?ex=656ecde5&is=655c58e5&hm=74c7e5fd1cde02976c292df8c7b5f6d07fd6467d55546ab984ce8058747493cd&

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var count = 0;
  var countOuter =0;
  var table=document.createElement("div");
  table.classList.add("parent-container")
  for(var i=0;i<(30);i++){ //SATIR
    
var tr=document.createElement("div");
tr.classList.add("child", "childno")
tr.classList.add(countOuter)
    table.appendChild(tr);
            tr.innerHTML=
            '<div id="'+count+'" class="emote_container">'+

                '<span id="'+count+'"  class="emote_name_lbl"> '+count+' </span>'+
            '</div>';
        count++;
        countOuter++;
    
    }
    document.getElementById("emotes_area").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("emotes_area").appendChild(table);
});


document.getElementById("input_search").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var searchValue = this.value.toLowerCase(); // Get the lowercase value of the input
  var emoteContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

  for (var i = 0; i < emoteContainers.length; i++) {
  var emoteName = emoteContainers[i].getElementsByClassName("emote_name_lbl")[0].innerText.toLowerCase();

  if (emoteName.includes(searchValue)) {
      emoteContainers[i].style.display = "flex"; // Show the emote container
  } else {
      emoteContainers[i].style.display = "none"; // Hide the emote container
  }
  }
});
```

```css
 .emotes_area{
  position: absolute;
  width: 404px;
  height: 703px;
  top: 165px;
  left: 62px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 1px;
background-color: #00000000;
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.emote_container{
  position: relative;
  width: 123px;
  height: 131px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(82.29% 82.29% at 50% 50%, rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.5) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 90%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px  #81818173;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2.7px;
}

/* New CSS */
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
    max-width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="emotes_area"  id="emotes_area">
        </div>
        
        <input class="search_input" id="input_search" type="text" placeholder="Search Something...">
        

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the question. Code-only answers aren't good answers

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "less is more". In the following snippet I used `display:inline-block` for the inner `div` elements. No `flex` or `grid` mechanics needed. And - of course - no strict corset of `table`-related elements, as this would prevent any re-shuffling of the filtered inner `div`s.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  let html="";
  for (let count = 0; count<30; count++) {     
    html+='<div id="'+count+'" class="emote_container">'+
          '<span id="'+count+'"  class="emote_name_lbl"> '+count+' </span></div>';
  }
  document.getElementById("emotes_area").innerHTML=html;
});


document.getElementById("input_search").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var searchValue = this.value.toLowerCase(); // Get the lowercase value of the input
  var emoteContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("emote_container");

  for (var i = 0; i < emoteContainers.length; i++) {
  var emoteName = emoteContainers[i].getElementsByClassName("emote_name_lbl")[0].innerText.toLowerCase();

  if (emoteName.includes(searchValue)) {
      emoteContainers[i].style.display = ""; // Show the emote container
  } else {
      emoteContainers[i].style.display = "none"; // Hide the emote container
  }
  }
});
```

```css
.emotes_area{
  position: absolute;
  width: 404px;
  height: 703px;
  top: 165px;
  left: 62px;
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 1px;
background-color: #00000000;
}

.emotes_area::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.emote_container{
  position: relative;
  width: 123px;
  height: 131px;
  background: radial-gradient(82.29% 82.29% at 50% 50%, rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.5) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 90%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px  #81818173;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2.7px;
}
.emotes_area div {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Emotes Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="emotes_area"  id="emotes_area">
<!-- <div class=""></div> -->
</div>

<input class="search_input" id="input_search" type="text" placeholder="Search Something...">

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use CSS display: grid property out here to achieve the similar type of design you are looking for and do away with Table structure.